# Use of Ternary Operator with addition in C++ Gives me wrong answer without brackets

Tags: c++

In this program what I am adding a number to the z based on some criteria where if x == 10 add 20 else 30. I tried with **ternary operator** but the **it is giving me wrong answer after removal of extra brackets**

Code 1 - Using ternary operator with extra brackets ###

```
    int x=10;
    int z = 10 + ((x == 10)? 20: 30); // used brackets here
    std::cout << z << std::endl; // output = 30, it is correct
```

Code 2 - Using ternary operator without extra brackets (Wrong result) ###

```
    int x=10;
    int z = 10 + (x == 10)? 20: 30; // not used brackets here 
    std::cout << z << std::endl; //output = 20; expected is 30
```

Comment: Have a look at operator preceedence please.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) - *Never*, ever include that header!

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: the answer for this question is

ternary operator precedence from right to left,
addition or substraction precedence from left to right,

without brackets the ternary operator treated from right to left so we got 20 as output in program 3

Comment: I am not sure why this question was closed. It is reproducible and the answer is simple, precedence of trinary operator is higher so the expression actually interpreted as this: `int z = (10 + (x == 10)) ? 20 : 30;` which means it will always be true because any bool + 10 will always result in `true`.